# How Create a VPN connection shortcut on home screen?

Tags: android

I have created a **Virtual private network connection** of https://aeroshield.me, now i just want to create a shortcut of Virtual private network connection on home screen in android phone.

Is it possible to **create a Virtual private network connection shortcut on home screen** of android phone Google nexus 5?

Answer (score 48):

As far as I know, the stock Android 5.0.1 on your Nexus 5 doesn’t have any widget that lets you create a shortcut to a VPN profile. But, it does have a Settings shortcut 1 x 1 widget that lets you create a shortcut to the VPN settings, which save you a few steps every time you want to connect to the VPN network.

If you’re fine with the Settings shortcut approach, here’s how to add one to your Home screen:

```
1- Long tap an empty area on any Home screen.
2- Tap Widgets.
3- Find, tap and drag the Settings shortcut to your home screen.
```

[image]

```
4- Select VPN, and you’re done.
```

[image]

In addition to the answer above, I haven’t come across any reliable 3rd party app that lets you create VPN profile shortcuts.

If you know of a better way that lets you create a shortcut to a VPN profile, share it in the comments.

Comment: This is brilliant and works perfectly with Android 9, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Nova Launcher Pro offers an `Activities` widget that can show directly the native VPN screen with the list of VPN connections.
You'll find the VPN screen under `Settings > VPN` (.Settings$VpnSettingsActivity).
Probably other advanced launchers offer a similar feature as well.

Answer (score 4):

PlayStore>Show VPN
or
VPN setting on home screen